# Registering Organisation in Drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

The Organization membership is of $200 and Individual membership cots $15.
I wanted to confirm that if an organization account has been made. Do i have to pay $15/per person to add team members in my organizatiom's lisiting??

Comment: This is probably best addressed to the organisation itself - questions of an ephemeral nature aren't really suitable to Q+A; their policies could change tomorrow and this post would immediately be confusing to future visitors

Comment: The answer is probably No. You simply can add any user independent from *their* Drupal Assoc membership.

Comment: This means only those members can be added to the organization team that have Drupal premium accounts ??

Comment: No matter their individual sponsorship, all people that chose your company as current organization within their profile edit's work tab will have the organization member badge in their profile, if your organization supports the Drupal Association. For further inquiries, I agree with Clive and suggest you check the "Have questions?" section of https://www.drupal.org/association/organization-membership

Answer (score 1):

If you take a organization membership, all the people in your organization will get an Organization member badge. You don't have to pay it separately.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i have to pay $15/per person to add team members in my
>   organizatiom's lisiting?

No.

The team members must add themselves.  They do so by editing their personal profile.  The right place is under the vertical tab "Work".  They must add the organization in the "Organzation" field and tick "Current organization".

There is no charge for doing this.

You *need* to make your team members do this as one of the steps towards getting your organization listed as a Service provider in the market place.